# Third Person: Rotate camera around player

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am trying to make a 3rd person game in the blender game engine but I do not know how to make a third person camera. So what I want is: Make the camera follow the player (cube) and rotate the camera around the player (cube) just like other 3rd person games like Uncharted and Grand Theft Auto.

Is something like this doable with Logic bricks? (if not then python code would be alright)

I am also quite new to the blender game engine, so please try to explain it as good as possible.

Blender Version: 2.76

Answer (score 0):

It is the same principle as with first person view:

- parent the camera to the character you want to follow
- use the mouse actuator (or any other method) to turn the camera according to you needs

The difference is:

- you do not place the camera around the (virtual) eyes - but somewhere behind the character.

Comment: Already tried that but the camera doesn't move **around** the object. It just stays in the same place and moves there and doesn't keep pointing at the object.

Comment: Does you character really move? Or are you playing an action that makes the bones move? This moves the mesh but not the object.